# Calling a function with a function-parameter and genric type for parameter and result

Tags: c#

I'm sorry, I'm having a hard time trying to describe my problem.

Let's say I have a base class and som classes that inherits from that base clase...

```c
    public abstract class BaseArgs
    {
        public abstract int CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class InvoicesArgs : BaseArgs
    {
        public override int CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ContactsArgs : BaseArgs
    {
        public override int CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have corrosponding result-base class and result classes that inherits...

```c
    public abstract class BaseResult
    {
        public abstract int RecordCount { get; set; }
        public abstract Exception Exception { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class InvoicesResult : BaseResult
    {
        public override int RecordCount { get; set; }
        public override Exception Exception { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ContactsResult : BaseResult
    {
        public override int RecordCount { get; set; }
        public override Exception Exception { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have functions that calls theses args and return the results...

```c
    public InvoicesResult GetInvoices(InvoicesArgs args)
    {
        InvoicesResult result = new InvoicesResult() { RecordCount = 100 };
        return result;
    }
    
    public ContactsResult GetContacts(ContactsArgs args)
    {
        ContactsResult result = new ContactsResult() { RecordCount = 55 };
        return result;
    }
```

My problem (which I need your help) is that I want to call a single common method and parse the method (GetInvoices or GetContacts) as a parameter with the right baseargs and return the right result .. like ...

```c
public class Test
{
    public async void Run()
    {
        InvoicesResult invoicesResult = await Run<InvoicesResult>(GetInvoices(), new InvoicesArgs() { CustomerID = 1 });
        InvoicesResult contactsResult = await Run<InvoicesResult>(GetContacts(), new ContactsArgs() { CustomerID = 1 });
    }
}
```

So my method (which does not work) looks like this:

```c
   public async static Task<T> Run<T>(Action<BaseArgs> function, BaseArgs args) where T : new()
    {
        T result = new T();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                result = function(args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Exception = ex;
            };
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Any idea how to create such a "common method"?

Again I'm sorry if I explained myself badly.

Comment: Whoever upvoting the question next please [edit] it to explain "which does not work". (I don't see OP to do that :) )

Comment: I think maybe there is a small unintentional error in your code.  Are you intending to set contactResult to await Run<InvoiceResult> or is that supposed to be ContactsResult?

Also I get the inheritance but are there any differences in your inheriting Result types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to solve the underlying problem you're trying to solve than the solution you've decided on. But here's code that would work:

```
    InvoicesResult invoicesResult = await Run(GetInvoices, new InvoicesArgs() { CustomerID = 1 });
    ContactsResult contactsResult = await Run(GetContacts, new ContactsArgs() { CustomerID = 1 });
```

```
public async static Task<TResult> Run<TArgs, TResult>(Func<TArgs, TResult> function, TArgs args)
    where TResult : BaseResult, new()
    where TArgs : BaseArgs
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            return function(args);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TResult { Exception = ex };
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: You're probably right that there is better ways. Your code works perfectly - thanks!! Your code has tought me a lot, so I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

Your function call is using an `Action<BaseArgs>`, which would look like a function call without a return: `public void some_function(BaseArgs args)` when what you want is to return T, so you need to use `Func<BaseArgs, T>` instead: `public T some_function(BaseArgs args)`.

`public async static Task<T> Run<T>(Func<BaseArgs, T> function, BaseArgs args) where T : new()`

Without tinkering with the code in an IDE, I can't recall whether a delegate can box a parameter to it's ancestor, so you might have to pull out BaseArgs and do something like this instead:

`public async static Task<TResult> Run<TArgs, TResult>(Func<TArgs, TResult> function, TArgs args) where TResult : new() where TArgs : BaseArgs`

In your actual function body, you reference result.Exception, however, there's no information in your function definition that gives the compiler enough information to infer that TResult has a property Exception, so you will have to include that TResult must inherit from BaseResult, making your final function definition:

`public async static Task<TResult> Run<TArgs, TResult>(Func<TArgs, TResult> function, TArgs args) where TResult : BaseResult, new() where TArgs : BaseArgs`

Then when you call it, you need to pass in the function as a delegate, otherwise you're just passing in the returned result of the function rather than the function itself, so you would use GetInvoices without parentheses.

The generic function Run should be able to implicitly pick the types TResult and TArgs from the delegate parameter without you having to write it out, so you can further simplify your call to: `await Run(GetInvoices, new InvoicesArgs { CustomerID = 1 })`.